# Wavesurfer v6.6.4 invalid progress bar

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

Due to incompatibility with some packages on a Vue project, `wavesurfer` needs to go down to `v6.6.4` from `v7.7.0`. And while trying to make player work again, I got stuck on progress bar.

Here's the problem: Progress bar is loaded with all its peaks from the start, it just expands as gets closer to finish:

[image: progress bar on 1 sec]
[image: progress bar on 2 sec]

```
this.baseAudioPlayer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: this.$refs.container as HTMLDivElement,
        waveColor: COLORS.GRAY_400,
        progressColor: COLORS.BLUE_700,
        barWidth: 3,
        barRadius: 4,
        height: 28,
        autoCenterImmediately: true,
        normalize: true
})

this.baseAudioPlayer.load(url)

... // init events: audioprocess, init, ready, finish.
// on ready event wavesurfer play method is called
```

I thought it could be some issue with params in `create`, but even if I leave only `container` property, problem still occurs.

Before downgrading `create` also had `fetchParams` and `dragToSeek` params.
Also `timeupdate` event was changed on `audioprocess`, cause on `6.6.4` such event didn't exist.